# How to use subfig, psfrag, and contour packages with LaTex

Tags: subfig, psfrag, contour

I'm trying to combine the aforementioned packages to produce a Figure in LaTex, but it isn't working correctly. The subfig and psfrag packages work correctly and the labels get replaced properly. However, when I include the contour command, only the label in the first image is replaced properly while the label in the second image is not replaced at all. Please check out the example below. I have also provided and image to illustrate what I'm referring to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\contourlength{.06em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    
    \psfrag{000}[c][c][10][00]{\color{red}\contour{black}{TEST}\color{black}}
    % \psfrag{000}[c][c][10][00]{\color{red}TEST\color{black}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{drawing.eps}}\\
    \psfrag{000}[c][c][10][00]{\color{red}\contour{black}{TEST}\color{black}}
    % \psfrag{000}[c][c][10][00]{\color{red}TEST\color{black}}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{drawing.eps}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Did I make a mistake? I mean, I provided a minimal working example and an image of the issue. Is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: **Yes!** To make you question understandable by someone who did not read its title.